# How to show routes between two geo coordinates in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to show routes between two geo coordinates in windows phone 8.

I tried a lot but was not able to succeed, I am able to get directions from my current location to a specific place using GeocodeQuery as below.

But what if i want to show route on map between just two geo coordinates, for example from 28.608554, 77.232922 to 28.630721, 77.220219?

```
        GeocodeQuery Mygeocodequery = new GeocodeQuery();
        Mygeocodequery.SearchTerm = "New Delhi, India";
        Mygeocodequery.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(myGeoposition.Coordinate.Latitude, myGeoposition.Coordinate.Longitude);
        Mygeocodequery.QueryCompleted += Mygeocodequery_QueryCompleted;
        Mygeocodequery.QueryAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you

[Location services and Maps](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2012/11/06/what-s-new-in-windows-phone-8-6-out-of-8-location-services-and-maps.aspx)